# Can't include JSON::XS module locally in CGI perl script but can include JSON module

Tags: json, perl, perl-module

So for a particular CGI perl script I have included JSON like this to handle some .json files:

```
use lib "./modules/JSON/lib";
use JSON;
```

This works fine and well. The web directory holds the files required in the modules folder.

However, the JSON module is very slow. I read that JSON:XS can be much, much faster but I can't seem to simply use it as so:

```
use lib "./modules/JSON-XS";
use JSON::XS;
```

There is no lib folder in the JSON-XS files, i've tried combinations of use (ie, using both folders and etc) but it didn't work.

And no I cannot simply install the module for this particular project.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I tried installing with the makefile. Two dependencies were needed:
`common::sense` and `Types::Serialiser` (the prereq for Types::Serialiser is `common::sense`).

I install common::sense fine and it passed make test but `Types::Serialiser` says: 

**Warning: prerequisite common::sense 0 not found.**

Comment: Okay using: `perl Makefile.PL PREFIX=/path/to/modules LIB=/path/to/modules` I was able to install all the modules successfully and pass the `make test` but am unsure how to actually use them in my script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay this finally worked for me:

I did this process to all the dependencies (in the order of no dependencies to more dependencies)

```
export PERL5LIB = ~/path/to/modules/perl5
perl Makefile.PL PREFIX=$PERL5LIB LIB=$PERL5LIB
make
make test
make install
```

This installed all modules into a directory I called perl5. It also means that when you try to install other modules locally the dependencies issue does not appear due to the PREFIX/LIB additions.

Then all I did was add this to my perl CGI script:

```
use lib "./modules/perl5";
use JSON::XS;
```

PS: JSON::XS is so much faster!

:D

Answer (score 2):

> And no I cannot simply install the module for this particular project.

You can't use a module without installing it. You've just been getting away with doing a half-assed job of it. That won't work for JSON::XS, though. The reason it's fast is because it's written in C, so you'll need to compile the C code. The easiest way by far to do this is to use the provided installer instead of reinventing the wheel.

(You do know you can install a module into any directory, and that this does not require special permissions, right?)

Comment: It seems like I was simply using JSON without installing it before which worked but it is a bad habit. I attempted to install it but am still having issues, the CGI environment produces a 500 error whenever i use JSON::XS;

Comment: Start by finding out what error caused the 500. Your web server should be configured to place this in a log file.

Answer (score 1):

Perl distributions are usually usable in an uninstalled state. What you just need to do is to call `perl Makefile.PL && make` (or for a `Module::Build`-based distribution: `perl Build.PL && ./Build`). This will do all necessary compilations (if it's an XS module) and copy the library files into the `blib` subdirectory. In your script instead of `use lib` you would write `use blib`:

```
use blib "/path/to/JSON-XS";
```

Note that if a module has dependencies, then you have to resolve it yourself and add that many `use blib` statements. `JSON::XS` does not have that many dependencies, but it will be really inconvenient for other modules. In this case you should probably seek another solution, e.g. using `CPAN.pm` together with `local::lib`.

Comment: Thanks for this reply, I created the makefile using perl and then used make. This did create all the libraries. However I am still unable to use it. The cgi environment produces a Error 500.

Comment: I also used all dependencies:

use blib "./modules/common-sense-3.72";
use blib "./modules/Types-Serialiser-0.03";
use blib "./modules/JSON-XS-3.01";

use common::sense;
use Types::Serialiser;
use JSON::XS;